# what's the difference between if not 3 in [1,2,4,5]: and if 3 not in [1,2,4,5]?

Tags: python

I'm new to python,so kindly please can anybody explain the difference between

```
if not 3 in [1,2,4,5]:
    print("true")
```

and

```
if 3 not in [1,2,4,5]:
    print("true")
```